# What is this "Vo LTE" notification bar icon?

Tags: notification-bar, notification-icons

This icon [image: Vo LTE icon] started showing up in my Android notification bar last week. I think it was after I used the Google Drive app for the first time (I had never opened this app before and was just curious).

Now the icon is there all the time, occupying valuable notification bar real estate – and not providing any useful information in return, as far as I can tell.

What is this icon? What is it supposed to be telling me?

Can I make it go away? If so, is there a reason not to?

[image: status bar with Vo LTE icon and freehand red circle]

Comment: I think you have activated VoLTE service for that SIM, you can set in phone Settings.

Comment: It means Voice over LTE network. It is good to leave it like that because you get better voice quality during calls.

Comment: Maybe it gives you the ability to use the phone and the data at the same time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VoLTE means Voice over [LTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTE_(telecommunication)). The icon notifies you that you are now able to phone over LTE. This means, it's not necessary in order to make a phone call to switch back to 3G (You cannot phone over normal LTE).
In short it's new and better. As far as I can tell you could disable VoLTE altogether, but I recommend you to simply live with it.

Comment: On some devices it shows up as `HD`

Answer (score 1):

VoLTE stands for voice over LTE. It means you can make HD voice/video calls over your LTE network.

Comment: _HD voice video calls_ JIO effect. Right??

Comment: Yeah correct @sagar :)

Answer (score 1):

VO-LTE is the next generation of VOIP.

It indicates that VOLTE is enabled in your device and you will be able to call via LTE.

It stands for Voice Over Long Term Evolution.

It is a technology works with 4G/LTE.

The VOLTE calls are highly secured and thus can't be taped

Answer (score 1):

I also started seeing this icon very recently on my Samsung phone. You can switch it off by following the path on your Samsung Android phone: Settings > Connections > Mobile Networks > VoLTE calls (off or on)

Comment: Following your steps does not only switch off the icon, it also switches off the underlying feature.

Answer (score 0):

it's describe your phone supported 4g Volte. and You can call without any third party app. EX jio4g voice.